# How do I get a list of PWA's (and there associated launch urls) that are running from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I have a chrome extension. The task is to get a list of PWA's (installed from Chrome) that are running on the OS and fetch the launch URL's of all those PWA's. I am not able to find any API provided by chrome extensions to achieve this. Would be really helpful if someone can guide me in the right direction

Comment: @woxxom could you please guide me on this?

Comment: `chrome.management.getAll` should list all installed PWAs. Then you can use chrome.tabs.query to find the tabs.

Comment: chrome://apps/ I can see my installed apps here, but don't think it'll work for an extension